# Nginx block for multiple domains to redirect all traffic to https?

Tags: nginx, configuration, https

I have a web server running nginx 1.6 with one IP address and hosting www.domainname.com as well as dev.domainname.com.

I'm trying to find a smart way to route all http traffic to https and I want to make sure that my default server is the 'www' live version of the time. So the end goal is that unless the user specifies https://dev.domainname.com they will be redirected to https://www.domainname.com.

My nginx.conf setup is configured to include for '/etc/nginx/etc/sites-enabled/*'. So my configuration example is located at 'etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.domainname.com'.

Also, to clarify. My current configuration has issues loading the dev site when you are visiting the domain without the www.

***Edit***: I just tried this method locally and http and https are not allowed in the '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/'. Is there a better solution or should I move this configuration into the nginx.conf?*

So my question is there a better way to handle this type of setup?

```
http {

# all traffic should be over https
listen 80 default;

# listen for all server names
server_name *.domainname.com;

# redirect to www with https
return 301 $scheme://www.domainname.com$request_uri;

}

https {

# configuration for all https sites
listen 443 default ssl;
ssl on;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# configuration for the non-www redirect
server {

    # non-www server name
    server_name domainname.com;
    # return to www
    return 301 $scheme://www.domainname.com$request_uri;

}

# configuration for the live website
server {

    # www server name
    server_name www.domainname.com;

    # root to public directory
    root /path/to/www.domainname.com/public;

    # ssl certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domainname.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domainname.com/server.key;

    # error logs for www site
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.domainname.com-error.log error;

}

# configuration for the dev site
server {

    # dev server name
    server_name dev.domainname.com;

    # root to public directory
    root /path/to/dev.domainname.com/public;

    # ssl certificates - using multi domain ssl
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domainname.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domainname.com/server.key;

    # error logs for dev site
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev.domainname.com-error.log error;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your distribution is Debian-based, you have `sites-available/default` file installed. That is the file that configures default pages for nginx.

You need to disable this virtual host by running its symlink with `rm sites-enabled/default`.

Then, you need to make a new `default` with the following content:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key;

    redirect 301 https://www.domainname.com$request_uri;
}
```

This block makes sure that all requests to other domains not listed everywhere get redirected to https://www.domainname.com.

Then, make another file, for example `dev.domainname.com`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name dev.domainname.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key;

    # Other config for dev.domainname.com
}
```

This block handles the requests for `dev.domainname.com`.

And finally, `www.domainname.com`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.domainname.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key;

    # Other config for www.domainname.com
}
```

And this block handles requests for `www.domainname.com`.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is this:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    *.domainname.com;
       return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat!